# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an InputStream,

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel, synthetica

I'm trying to costumize a `Synthetica` theme in `netbeans` as this article shows :

http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1335947397000

So, I created the costum.xml file and I added it to my project folder as : `/home/aimad/NetBeansProjects/GestionStock/costum.xml`

and I create this code in my Form constructor :

```
public PersonelMainForm() {
        try {
            try {

                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel() {
                    @Override
                    protected void loadCustomXML() throws ParseException {

                        loadXMLConfig("custom.xml");

                    }
                });

                setName("MainFrame");
                getRootPane().updateUI();


            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PersonelMainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonelMainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        initComponents();
    }
```

but when I run the program I get this error message :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an InputStream,
>   StyleFactory and Class or URL     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthParser.parse(SynthParser.java:227)    at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.load(SynthLookAndFeel.java:573)
>     at
>   de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.loadXMLConfig(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:428)
>     at
>   Personel.PersonelMainForm$1.loadCustomXML(PersonelMainForm.java:34)
>     at
>   de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:364)
>     at
>   de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel.(SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel.java:30)
>     at Personel.PersonelMainForm$1.(PersonelMainForm.java:30)     at
>   Personel.PersonelMainForm.(PersonelMainForm.java:30)    at
>   Personel.PersonelMainForm$3.run(PersonelMainForm.java:159)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: The String "custom.xml" is not a valid parameter. You need to simply a URL/InputStream reference to the file

Comment: @MadProgrammer hw can I do that ?

Comment: I depends, where is the `custom.xml` file stored

Comment: @MadProgrammer as I motioned is located in : /home/aimad/NetBeansProjects/GestionStock/costum.xml

Comment: There's a spelling difference between the files...